# Get parameter from custom URL handler

Tags: java, url, parameters

I created a custom URL handler that runs my Java application successfully (that is an exe file generated after maven buid). Below is what I did and added the handler to registery.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\my]
@="URL:my Protocol" 
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\my\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\my\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\myApp.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\my\shell\open\ddeexec]
@=""
"NoActivateHandler"=""
```

and in my test.html, I have

```
<a href="my:go/id=guest">My Application Start</a>
```

How can I get the parameter pass(id in the link) passed from URL inside the application?

Comment: So please include you code.

Comment: What kind of handler?

Comment: What are you using? Servlets?

Comment: to avoid confusion: Could you please revert your question to its original state and add your solution as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used to register :

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myApp]
@="URL:myApp Protocol handled by CustomURL"
"URL Protocol"=""
"CustomUrlApplication"="C:\\temp\\eclipse.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myApp\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\temp\\eclipse.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myApp\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myApp\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myApp\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\temp\\eclipse.exe %1"
```

the link in my html file looking like this :

```
<a href="myApp:go/USER">Application Start</a>
```

then I could get whole link inside my application via :

```
String[] args = Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: This certainly cut my hours in trying to deliver the exact same solution. But, with what maven build archtype are you able to generate the *.exe file? or, wait, is this an Eclipse RPC application?

Comment: It's an Eclipse RPC application.